# Is it possible to mark a question as favorite in the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, bookmarks

How do I add a question to my favorites in the Stack Exchange Android application?

Comment: With all due respect, I see this as a perfect example of the older question being the duplicate, or in this case potentially obsolete. As stated in the answer here, the current version of the app has a "favorite" button at the bottom of each question. The duplicate this links to is from an older version, when it was necessary to open a menu and choose "favorite."  I think this question should stay open, and the older one closed.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.0.57 there's a "favorite" button at the bottom of the question, next to the "share" button.